# error when trying to run composer install - "requirements could not be resolved"

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I started working with PHPUnit a few days ago and came across this issue.
I want to test some classes in a project i cloned from github. 
in the project there are two folders: "tests" and "src" and in each one of them `composer.json` file.
in the src folder the file looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
      "php": ">=5.3.0",
      "monolog/monolog": "1.*",
      "slim/slim": "2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
    "classmap": ["classes/"]
    }
}
```

and in the tests folder the file looks like this:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "adServerTesting": ""
        }
    }
}
```

so i created this one united `composer.json` :

```
{
    "require": {
      "php": ">=5.3.0",
      "monolog/monolog": "1.*",
      "slim/slim": "2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
    "classmap": ["classes/"],
        "psr-0": {
            "adServerTesting": ""
        }
    }
}
```

but when i run `composer install` i get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit dev-master -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[dev-master].
    - phpunit/phpunit dev-master requires php >=5.6 -> your PHP version (5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

since i have phpunit installed on my machine i tried to run the `composer install` from inside the `src` folder path and great, command and tests executed properly but now after uniting the files i get this error. I see it says i have php 5.5.9 which i need to upgrade but than why did it work when i run the `composer install` from the src folder?? thx..

Comment: try with this version: `"phpunit/phpunit": "4.2.*",` in the composer.json

Comment: The current stable version is PHPUnit 4.7, not PHPUnit 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

`phpunit/phpunit:@dev` reuqires PHP 5.6 and your PHP version is 5.5.

Use lower version of PHPUnit, or rather let composer decide that. You can do that by calling:

`composer require phpunit/phpunit --dev`

`--dev` option for adding to `require-dev` section.